# How to use Menu component from react native paper inside of my header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> I am trying to use Menu from react native paper inside of my header but when pressing the button that is supposed to show the Menu, it doesn't work, it simply does nothing. But when I do it outside of my header and I press the button that is supposed to show the menu it works and shows all the items as desired. Does anyone knows how I can fix that? Here is my code:

```
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const openMenu = () => setVisible(false);

  const closeMenu = () => setVisible(false);


  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({

      

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      },


      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'black',      
      },


      headerLeft: () => <FontAwesome5 name='user-circle' style={{right: -15}} onPress={navigation.toggleDrawer} size={28} solid/>,
    })}>

        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={BottomTab} 
        options={{         
          title: '',
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        
        
          
        headerRight: () => (

          
          <View>    
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>


          
              <View style={{left: -60}}>

              <Provider>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingTop: 0,
          left: 0,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          textAlign: 'center',
          top: 0,
        }}>
        <Menu
          visible={visible}
          onDismiss={closeMenu}
          anchor={<Pressable onPress={openMenu}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', backgroundColor: 'red', paddingRight: 30}}>
            Popular
          </Text>
</Pressable>}>
            

          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 1" />
          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 2" />
          <Divider />
          <Menu.Item onPress={() => {}} title="Item 3" />
        </Menu>
      </View>
    </Provider>
        


                {/*<Pressable onPress={() => console.log('Pressed Popular')}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', backgroundColor: 'white', paddingRight: 30}}>
                    Popular
                  </Text>
      </Pressable>*/}
                
                
              </View>
              


              <MaterialIcons
              onPress={() => console.log('Pressed Popular')}
              name="expand-more"
              size={30}
              style={{left: -80}}
      /> 
            


              <Feather
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Create')}
              name="plus-circle"
              color="black"              
              size={30}
              style={{right: 15, top: 0}}
              />
            

          </View>




          </View>
          ),
          }}
          />
```

Comment: Header won't re-render directly by updating states. You can use `useEffect` or  `useLayoutEffect()` with dependency to trigger re-render when menu is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it seems to work when you use [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) in your Screen file combined with a [useLayoutEffect](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useLayoutEffect).

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Appbar, Menu } from 'react-native-paper';

const VehicleDetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation
}: StackScreenProps<VehiclesStackParamList, 
"VehicleDetails">) => {
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
const { vehicle } = route.params;
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: vehicle.name,
  headerRight: () => (
    <View style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
      <Menu
        visible={visible}
        onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)}
        anchor={
          <Appbar.Action
            icon="dots-vertical"
            onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
          />
        }
      >
        <Menu.Item
          onPress={() => {
            setVisible(false);
            setEditMode(true);
          }}
          title="Edit"
        />
        <Divider />
        <Menu.Item
          onPress={() => {
            setVisible(false);
          }}
          title="Delete"
        />
      </Menu>
    </View>
  ),
});
}, [navigation, visible]);

return (Your screen code)
```

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed it is create the menu component outside the main component where the navigator is defined. Then pass all the necessary things as props to the menu component (and I think it works maybe because the re-render is not triggered in the older case).

```
const MoreButton = ({
  showDropDown,
  setShowDropDown,
  closeMenu,
  dropDownListAndFunction,
}) => {
  return (
    <Menu
      visible={showDropDown}
      anchor={
        <IconButton
          icon="dots-vertical"
          onPress={() => setShowDropDown(true)}
        />
      }
      onDismiss={closeMenu}
    >
      <Menu.Item title='option' />
    </Menu>
  );
};

const MainFile = () => {

 return <YourNavgator />
}
```